# numlockx no longer works after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10

Repeated what has worked for me in the past without any success. And no, there's not an option in the BIOS. This sucks. It's a minor issue, but it attacks my laziness which is forbidden! o_0

Answer (score 6):

- Install NumLockX: Ctrl+Alt+T, insert: `sudo apt-get install numlockx` (Ctrl+Shift+V)
- Open with su lightdm.conf: Alt+F2 insert: `gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (Ctrl+V)
- Insert line: `greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on` (Ctrl+V)
- Save it (Ctrl+S)
- Reboot your computer.
- Enjoy!

Comment: U da Man! Much Thx

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @Almaz I have the same problem in my 14.04 LTS, please provide me a solution...