# How to set up Ubuntu 11.10 to automatically turn NumLock on when boot-up?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [numlockx no longer works after upgrade to 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67952/numlockx-no-longer-works-after-upgrade-to-11-10)

Befor 11.10 ubuntu，I can do:
sudo apt-get install numlockx

and edit /etc/gdm/Init/Default

but in 11.10, I can't find /etc/**gdm**! How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "*greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on*" 
at the end in */etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf*

Hope it helps.