# Is there a way to enable the keyboard numblock?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard

My habit is to use the numblock on my keyboard if I have to type in numbers. Is there a way to enable the numblock in Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: Yes there is: just press NumLock button on your keypad

Comment: Maybe you mean this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67952/numlockx-no-longer-works-after-upgrade-to-11-10

Comment: Press NumLock button: fail. So I'll try the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd>... one of these may enable <kbd>NumLock</kbd> again.

Answer (score 1):

If u want it to be ON upon start then

Heres wiki https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock

Heres my fast solution so you dont need to read wiki ;) in terminal paste this and press enter `sudo apt-get install numlockx && echo "/usr/bin/numlockx on" | sudo tee -a /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`
then reboot